# doPost after a forward servlets

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

i'm new using JSP & servlets so i don't know if i'm in right way to do this. so here it goes.

I'm trying to do a doPost with my firstServlet to fill a table then with the second I'm gonna try to do an insert but I need the datas from the index.jsp table but when i execute the secondServlet i get a null data

index.html

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr> 
            <td id="data"><%=(String)request.getAttribute("data") %> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <form action="firstServlet" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="text1">
        <input type="submit" id="btn">
    </form>
    <form action="secondServlet" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="text2">
        <input type="submit" id="btn">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

firstServlet

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class firstServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/firstServlet")
public class firstServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public firstServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.setAttribute("data", "Here's my data");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        //doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

secondServlet

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class secondServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/secondServlet")
public class secondServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public secondServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String s = (String) request.getAttribute("data");
        request.setAttribute("data", s);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        //doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to pass data using the `HttpSession` Object.

In your first servlet's doPost you will have something like this:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("DATA", "Here's my data");
```

And in the second Servlet you can retrieve your data like this:

```
String myData = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("DATA");
```

From now on this DATA attribute will remain in the user's session as long as the session is valid. You can remove the attribute from session using:

```
session.removeAttribute("DATA"); //OR request.getSession().removeAttribute("DATA");
```

Comment: @OscarFlores dont forget that if an answer helps you you can upvote it and accept it so that other users find it easier to spot helpfull answers